# DescribeSObject for Wrapper class

Tags: wrapper-class, describesobject, describes

Is it possible to describe an Inner classes object such as

```
public class DataTableWrapper 
{
    public DataTableWrapper()
    {
        objectRecordData = new List<ObjectRecordData>();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer page {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer total {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<ObjectRecordData> objectRecordData {get;set;}
}

public class ObjectRecordData
{
    public ObjectRecordData(){}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String name {get;set;}

}
```

I've tried things like this

```
AuraDataTableController.DataTableWrapper dtw = new AuraDataTableController.DataTableWrapper();
Schema.SObjectType dataTable = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('dtw');
//Schema.SObjectType dataTable = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(dtw);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = dataTable.getDescribe();
```

In all my research it doesn't appear to be possible, My goal is to be able to know the field type of`ObjectRecordData.name`(String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism you are looking for is called [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) in e.g. Java but such a mechanism has not been made available in Apex. It may eventually be - see this 8 year old idea [Apex Reflection](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVaAAK).

You don't explain what problem you are trying to solve: in the code you posted you obviously can hard code the type.

But you can make your UI more data driven by introducing your own hard-coded metadata if you want to e.g.:

```
public class ObjectRecordData
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Map<String, Type> meta {get;set;}

    public ObjectRecordData() {
        this.meta = new Map<String, Type>{
            'name' => String.class,
            'dob' => Date.class
        };
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String name {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Date dob {get;set;}
}
```

if in fact the classes are all hard-coded so that reflection isn't required. In this example the UI can determine the type from the `meta` field data via the field name string used as a key. ([DisplayType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm) might be a better choice than `Type` for something like that as it is more fine-grained for text fields.)

Comment: I didn't give the problem I'm trying to solve for because I was trying to figure out if It was even possible at first, what I'm trying to do is build a generic wrapper that can dynamically figure out how to to build itself.  I think this is a very good start and something I can use to build on.

Comment: @EricSSH Manual steps - forcing the coder to do more stuff or requiring someone to add configuration data - can make up for the missing dynamic capability if you don't need to do too much of it. And it also allows you to add extra information e.g. a UI label that you won't be able to get from the raw reflection data (if that mechanism is ever delivered).

Comment: That's where I am at right now..  I'm in a weird discovery phase of what do I make the coder do and what can I have config for.  The least amount of work for the Dev to do vs over development and effort, maybe I could abstract this out, but that will be a follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to dynamically describe custom object types (`Apex Class`). This functionality is only available for custom **`SObject`** types. If you want to use it dynamically, you will likely need to use the **[`Tooling API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm)**. Specifically, you would need to parse the **[`SymbolTable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm?search_text=symboltable)** of your `innerClasses` and then parse its `properties`.